# Как реализовать кнопку "поделиться" в мобильном приложении?

Tags: c#, windows, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, windows-phone-7

подскажите, какой метод API лучше использовать чтобы реализовать кнопку "поделиться" в мобильном приложении? есть конечно метод wall.post, но через него это делать очень муторно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=wall.addLike